# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python

hola como estan el ejercicio plantea que recibo una lista  de nombre name de 3 letras mayusculas y una variable llamada shift que puede ser entre -999 a 999 y debo encriptar usando el proceso cesar hasta mi codigo es este, pero se que el primer for solo guarda una letra de las 3 y el segundo for me da error : `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

```
import string
name = ['B', 'C', 'Z']
cesar = []
cesar1 = []
shift = 49

if abs(shift) > 26:
    shift = shift % 26
else:
    shift=shift


for i in range(0,len(name)):
    if (ord(name[i]) + shift)>90:
        cesar = 64 + ((ord(name[i]) + shift)-90) 
    else:
        cesar = (ord(name[i])+ shift)
for i in cesar():
    cesar1= chr(cesar(i))

print (cesar1)
```

Comment: `for i in cesar():` -> No tienes ningún método llamado `cesar()`, de hecho, `cesar` es un entero, y eso es precisamente lo que te dice el error, no puedes *llamar* a un entero como si fuese una función. Es decir, lo que estás intentando hacer es: `x = 4` y luego `x()`! Por cierto, declara cesar como array, pero nunca *metes valores* en ese array, si no que lo machacas con un entero. En python eso no da error puesto que ese array no está *tipado*, pero imagino que no es lo que quieres hacer. Te recomiendo repasar cómo trabajar con arrays :)

Answer (score 0):

Veo que usas muchas validaciones y algunas no son necesarias, por ejemplo:

```
if abs(shift) > 26:
    shift = shift % 26
else:
    shift=shift
```

Aquí solo sacas el residuo si es mayor que 26, y si no reasignas el mismo valor. Esto no es necesario ya que si sacas el residuo de un numero menor que 26 te dará el mismo numero. Aparte estas sacando el valor absoluto de `shift`, siendo que el valor puede ser positivo o negativo y esto en la encriptación cesar te indica hacia donde recorrer, si izquierda o derecha.

Puedes simplificar todo de la siguiente manera:

```
name = ['A', 'C', 'Z'] # Lista de letras
shift = 23  #Espacios a recorrer, positivo indica hacia la derecha
cesar = [] # Aquí se guarda el resultado final

for i in name: #Rrecorres el arreglo
    letraId = ord(i)-64 # Sacas el valor unicode y le restas 64
    if ((letraId+shift)%26) == 0: # Si es igual a cero es 'Z'
        newLetra = 'Z'
        cesar.append(newLetra) #Agregas a la lista
    else:
        newLetra = chr(((letraId+shift)%26)+64) #Obtienes de unicode a char
        cesar.append(newLetra) #Agregas a la lista

print(cesar) #Imprime la lista
```